# Does Health Connect available for Wear OS..?

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, healthconnect

I want to implement Health Connect on Wear OS-based SmartWatch.
But not getting any concreate information whether Health Connect supports Wear OS or not.
Also, Health Platform is going to deprecate soon.
Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Health Connect isn't available for Wear OS at this time. If your Wear OS app has a [companion mobile app](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer) you can integrate Health Connect with your mobile app.

Any data you'd want to write from your Wear OS app to Health Connect would need to be written to your mobile app, and any data you'd want to read from Health Connect to display on Wear OS would also flow through your mobile app.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the answer.
Can you please share any such example link if you have it handy..